# SageMath,kernel problems

Tags: math, sage

I installed sageMath 9.3 from this server  https://www.sagemath.org/download.html (I accessed the link from github for Windows) and when I use the plot function to create graphics I get this message.

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Here an example of a function that I want to implement.

```
x=var('x')
f(x)=sin(x)/x
plot(f(x),-1,1)
```

What should I do in order to be able to create graphs?